# Django Display images and use External CSS and Javascript

Tags: django

I want to display images in my html page. I tried to display images in templates but didn't display. I give codes give below check whether its correct and give some idea.

```
userreg(project name)
|-- media
|-- images
|    |-- linkedin.png
|
|-- registration(APP)
|    |--TEMPLATES
|
|--URLS.PY
|--SETTINGS.PY


SETTINGS.PY

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/var/www/userreg/static/'

TEMPLATES

<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/linkedin.png" />
```

check whether its correct or not and clear the error on above code. Give some example for adding external css and javascript in html templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MEDIA_URL` should be used for serving user uploaded content and for serving static files, `STATIC_URL` can be used. Try the following settings

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'media'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in your template

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/linkedin.png" />
<link type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?

Comment: The error is so clear. Add a comma in `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.

Comment: how to call external css and javascript in template